# iOS - App crashed because it attempted to access privacy - sensitive data without a usage description

Tags: ios

I get the following error:

`[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.`

Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crash requesting authorisation to Photos Library in iOS 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643179/crash-requesting-authorisation-to-photos-library-in-ios-10)

Answer (score 12):

These are set in the `plist` for your project. You can add/remove these by navigating to your target info inspector and expanding the "Custom iOS Target Properties" section. For example, one of the entries here in a project of mine is:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Allows user to capture a photo or video to upload to their family circle
```

You can see how this looks here:

[image: example of project inspector]

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to your Info.plist, add a new row and paste `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` into the key column. Then in the value column give a description as to why you need to access the user's photo library. Repeat the same step with `NSCameraUsageDescription` if you intend to use the device's camera.