# This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description, even with usage description

Tags: ios, xcode

This question is similar to the following question: [iOS - App crashed because it attempted to access privacy - sensitive data without a usage description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944993/ios-app-crashed-because-it-attempted-to-access-privacy-sensitive-data-withou)

I followed it as it says and I have Info.plist with the following key-value pair as suggested:

Key:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

Value:

```
This app requires access to your photo library to select your profile image
```

However, I still get the following error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is description for photo library. While what you have added is for camera description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription is not Camera Usage. It is Photo Library usage. You still have not done what the error message is telling you to do. Add a Photo Library usage key-value pair to your *Info.plist*.